# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть html страница, которую нужно спарсить. Сначала пытался сделать это с помощью simple html dom, но он отказался, так как MAX_FILE_SIZE > 600 000 почти в 2 раза, пытался спарсить с помощью preg_match_all, которая в свою очередь первый раз хорошо работает, а на второй вызов бросает `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35 bytes) in Z:\home\localhost\www\parser\1.php on line 50`. Страница весит 1218кб

```
$html = file_get_contents('source.html');
//$url = "http://46.4.130.245:8080/scripts/grabber/serp-test.php?site=semyadro.pro";

preg_match_all("#span class='big'>(.*?)<#", $html, $loss);

$res['poterianie'] = $loss[1][0];
$res['viroschie'] = $loss[1][1];
$res['prosevschie'] = $loss[1][2];
$res['novie'] = $loss[1][3];

preg_match_all('#<div class=\'color_main || medium\'>(.*?)</div>#', $html, $sites);// fatal error here(
```

как исправить? в чем проблема?

Comment: Не верю. Неэкранированные метасимволы `||` являются синтаксической ошибкой и `preg_match_all` не будет выполнятся, а просто вернет ошибку синтаксиса. Соответственно он не может занять столько оперативной памяти. Приведите реальное регулярное выражение. Оптимизировать по времени выполнения и занимаемой памяти данное регулярное выражение можно. Достаточно заменить `(.*?)<` на `((?:[^<]++|<)*?)<`

Comment: именно в `||` была ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем случае проблема может решиться выделением процессу большего объёма памяти.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
```

Но более правильно парсить большие XML-файлы, читая их порциями. Вот, почитайте:
http://php.net/manual/ru/book.xml.php

Я с этим расширением работаю уже год. Прекрасно разбираются файлы в 100 М и больше.

Comment: но у меня не xml, а html.  как можно читать по частям?

Comment: Простите, не знаю - не приходилось сталкиваться с большими HTML. Попрробуйте почитать тут: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.dom.php Если там и нет по частям - всё ж лучше, чем регуляркой парсить...